# (Method Not Allowed) external xml to json

Tags: javascript, xml, json, angularjs

I'm using this tutorial:
http://rabidgadfly.com/2013/02/angular-and-xml-no-problem/

to make starting an application of XML,
when I set the external xml (Feedburner) tells me that I have no access, anyone know what it could be?

HTML:

```
<section ng-controller="AppController" class="container-podcastapp">
         <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="guitar in dataSet">
               <div class="resultwrapper">
                   <h2>{{item.title}}</h2>
                </div>
            </li>   
          </ul>
    </section>
```

javascript:

```
angular.module('myApp.service',[]).
    factory('DataSource', ['$http',function($http){
       return {
           get: function(file,callback,transform){
                $http.get(
                    file,
                    {transformResponse:transform}
                ).
                success(function(data, status) {
                    console.log("Request succeeded");
                    callback(data);
                }).
                error(function(data, status) {
                    console.log("Request failed " + status);
                });
           }
       };
    }]);

angular.module('myApp',['myApp.service']);

var AppController = function($scope,DataSource) {

    var SOURCE_FILE = "http://rss.cnn.com/services/podcasting/ac360/rss.xml";

    xmlTransform = function(data) {
        console.log("transform data");
        var x2js = new X2JS();
        var json = x2js.xml_str2json( data );
        return json.item;
    };

    setData = function(data) {
        $scope.dataSet = data;
    };

    DataSource.get(SOURCE_FILE,setData,xmlTransform);

};
```

Answer (score 0):

"Method not allowed" normally means that the service you're sending the request to is configured to forbid a certain request type (`POST`, `GET`, `OPTIONS`).

Since you're trying (as far as I can tell) to use the `GET` method, I'd suggest trying using `POST`.

On the other hand, in some cases the server will forbid cross domain ajax requests alltogether - quite possibly this URL you're querying isn't really a static file on the server but some kind of service, in which case it has to be configured to allow Ajax requests from a different domain.

If you could post the entire error/response you get (using Fiddler or whatever) it would be helpful, in case using `POST` doesn't do the job.

*Edit:*

Try making the following change to your service:

```
angular.module('myApp.service',[]).
factory('DataSource', ['$http',function($http){
   return {
       get: function(file,callback,transform){
            $http.post(file, {}, {transformResponse:transform}). // this is the change
            success(function(data, status) {
                console.log("Request succeeded");
                callback(data);
            }).
            error(function(data, status) {
                console.log("Request failed " + status);
            });
       }
   };
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. if you see it in the example above, the only thing that changed was the local file to url: var source_file = "guitars.xml," to: var source_file = "http://rss.cnn.com/services/ podcasting/ac360/rss.xml ";

also changed the return:
return json.channel.item;

Thanks.

Comment: Well that makes sense - when accessing a local XML file, you're effectively making a `GET` request to some static local resource and that works. When switching over to the said URL, you're making a `GET` request to a resource that might be dynamically created by some underlying service, and if that service is configured to accept only `POST` requests (as is very often the case) you'll get the `Method not allowed` error. Did you try using `$http.post()`? Just don't forget that `post()` takes 3 parameters: url, data (in your case a blank `{}`) & config.

Comment: put the modified code that you put me and still generates this error:
http://i.imgur.com/nPVVHz6.jpg

Thanks

Comment: From what I see, you now get a 404 error... nothing to do with this problem, it just means that the xml file isn't there. I tried accessing the URL you talked about earlier @ cnn.com and it blocks cross domain requests alltogether. So just find some static xml file that you know you can access for sure, and work with that (with either get/post, depends on the server).